# How avoid multiple IF loops in Java

Tags: java

What is the best way to avoid multiple `if` blocks which is used for `null` checks in Java?

The following is my sample code. Which one is the most optimized way?

```
if (address!=null} {
    if (firstName!=null) {
        if (lastName!=null) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Different approach, use the required option in your HTML form. Take a look here [link]http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tags/p/required-attribute.htm[/link] (there are many other sources but this one just showed up first)

Comment: Careful with client-side checking, it is never sufficient, if he is not running an html5 browser, the required will be useless

Comment: Your sample code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 10):

Use `&&`. `&&` is logical and. `&&` combines two values and returns a boolean which is true if and only if both of its operands are true

```
if(address!=null && firstName!=null && lastName!=null)
{
}
```

For instance

```
boolean b;
b = 3 > 2 && 5 < 7; // b is true
b = 2 > 3 && 5 < 7; // b is now false
```

Answer (score 7):

Use and operator (&&)

```
   if(address!=null && firstName!=null && lastName!=null) 
    {
      //DoSomething here 
    }
```

And I suggest you to see  [**Short circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: +1, for being the first correct answer, Not sure why it is downvoted.

Comment: @Habib thankyou :) I guess even those are not sure why they downvoted :)

Comment: He/She downvoted mine one too.Without any reason

Comment: @freak No worries :) No one here become king and no one become begger.Move on.ignore those downvotes without comments.Get help from here and help others if you can :)

Comment: yes this is the best thing :)

Answer (score 7):

**`if loop` is a wrong word. You should say `if statements`** 
As in you case you can use OR (||) or AND (&&)statement like this

```
if(address!=null && firstName!=null && lastName!=null)
{
}
```

*Try `AND(&&)` if you want to pass all checks or intead of nested if statements and try `OR(||)` for non nested like `else if` or simply say if you want to pass anyone of your condition* 
But 
if all of these are Strings then you should try like this 
`"yourValue".equals(stringValue)`
This will skip the null check.

Comment: @downvoter please care to comment.otherwise i will flag it to the moderator

Comment: don't flag it for moderation, because it would be declined. But yes downvoter should leave comment IMO

Comment: ok i dint know about this.I thought here we can flag for any type of attention to the moderator.thanks bro :)

Answer (score 3):

there are no if LOOPS

```
boolean complete = address != null && firstName != null && lastName != null;
if (complete) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
public boolean notNulls(Object ... args) {
    for(Object arg : args)
        if (arg == null) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Use:

```
if (notNulls(address, firstName, lastName)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: more complex rather than simple If

Answer (score -1):

As others point out, a logical and (&&) is probably the best way to consolidate your logic. An && operation will only evaluate to `true` if both sides evaluate to `true`.

```
if (address != null && firstName != null && lastName != null) {
    // Whatever you want to do with that...
} else {
    // Whatever you want to do with bad input
}
```

For the sake of diversity, you could also use a try-catch approach. In Java, a NullPointerException will be thrown if you try to call a method on a null value, which you can catch and handle.

```
try {
    // Whatever you want to do with that...
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    // Whatever you want to do with bad input
}
```

This approach can be helpful if you've got a really big set of inputs that might be null, although in general I wouldn't advocate it. (The problem with the second approach is that if you call some other method from the `try` part that triggers a NullPointerException, it will end up in the `catch` block here, even though it may be totally unrelated to these inputs - i.e. you could make it hard for yourself to spot a bug in a different part of your program.)

Comment: Code should never throw `NullPointerException` under normal circumstances. A catch block may hide the original error, causing other more subtle errors in its wake. [Strict Exception Rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.6/rules/strictexception.html)

Comment: I concur (that's what I was getting at in my last paragraph, albeit not so succinctly). It is necessary to understand what _can_ be done in a language before understanding what _should_ be done; since the OP self-identifies as a beginner at Java, I think this is relevant.